# setting the value of textbox equal to address bar in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I set the Textbox's value equal to address bar?

for example :

```
localhost:28362/?f=Ava
```

when we click on a button the value of textbox must set to : Ava 
?

Comment: Do you need to have this done on client-side?

Comment: it doesn't matter but,client-side better

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Add Query String Jquery Js(`querystring-0.9.0-min.js`) in solution

```
 $("#ButtonId").click(function(){
       $("#textBoxID").val($.QueryString("f");)
 });
```

Comment: jQuery has no such method "QueryString"

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich Please read http://www.darlesson.com/jquery/querystring/?language=en&province=Alberta&province=Ontario&province=Quebec

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to include such a plugin for this simple problem.

Comment: For better performance and code you can add this is just 3 KB file

Answer (score 1):

Here is Javascript function to get query string value:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then you need to assign this value to a textbox. I would use jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $("#myTextBoxID").val(getParam("f"));

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that uses MVC4 rather than JavaScript, define your controller method as:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string f) {
      return View(f);
  }
```

In your view, you would then use one of:

```
  @model string;
  @Html.TextBoxFor(Model)
```

or

```
  @model string
  <input type='text' value='@Model' name='myValue' />
```

Obviously this is vastly oversimplified, but should give you a good starting point.